# HAproxy: "reverseproxy-relation-changed" in Landscape Dense Maas bundle

Tags: juju

**Landscape Dense-MAAS bundle Lab:**

All virtual environment has been realised using Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS and so composed:

- 1 VM for MAAS (memory: 8GB, CPU: 1, HDD: 500GB);
- 1 VM for JUJU GUI (memory: 8GB, CPU: 1, HDD: 500GB);
- 1 VM for LANDSCAPE (memory: 8GB, CPU: 1, HDD: 500GB);

[image]

while on JUJU

[image]

during the deploy of Landscape Dense-MAAS via JUJU GUI I've received this error on HAproxy:

```
Status: error - hook failed: "reverseproxy-relation-changed"
Agent Status: executing
Workload Status: error
Public addresses:
10.20.81.3
IP addresses:
10.20.81.3
```

the complete juju status is [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/24414426/), I've also pasted the last 200 lines [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/24420200/), let me know if you need more lines. I saw the line that report the error [ALERT] 109/133058 (5548) but I don't know how to resolve that.
I'm trying more time to deploy that bundle on my lab but the result is always the same.

**update my lab:**

during some tests, I've tried to deploy that bundle using this time the cli with the following command:

**$: juju deploy landscape-dense-maas**

as the right procedure, the node is passed in deployed status and juju deployed the bundle without receive any issue...

[image]

obtaining the gui of Landscape

[image]

I've re-build more time the same lab, destroyed each time the its juju model, and using the gui or the cli with the following command, as suggest in official bundle:

**$: juju deploy cs:bundle/landscape-dense-maas-7**

in both case the issue with HAproxy is always present. Is there anyone has the same my issue and can help me?

Comment: anyone can help me?

Comment: Can you also provide the juju config output for haproxy and landscape-server? It seems that the haproxy server config isn't happy and so there might be missing config for the ssl cert to be used?

Comment: same issue with ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I've tried the same think 2 years later and usign Juju controller to deploy landscape obtained the same issue while using a command line no problems!!!!!!